# Animation effect one screen to another screen?

Tags: android

When i go to one activity to another activity ,can i do effect?

It is possible? If it is possible, can anybody give me some reference or snippet please?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok look at this Demo code on the dev site:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html

The key lines are:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
```

Android has some standard animations or you can create them yourself in XML and save them inside "res/anim"